# Make a right click with Super ( or another key )+left click

Tags: unity, touchscreen

I have an xps 13 (2015), I can't manage to make a right click with the touchscreen by any means.

I tought a good solution would be to make a <kbd>Super</kbd>+left click, a bit like the <kbd>alt</kbd>+left click to drag a window (which works perfectly with my touchscreen).

What I want to do is **not doable** with a simple shortcut, I would like to be able to push a letter while making a simple click on the touchscreen with the other hand, where I want to make the right click.

A simple right click shortcut would rightclick anywhere, not where I actually want to click.

But I haven't found any mean to achieve it.

Comment: doesn't it work if you press-down for few seconds and lift your finger - like in smartphones etc?

Comment: Not exactly, I dont want a keyboard shortcut, I want the same thing than alt+left click (to grab a window) but in order to right click. And Ron, your solution works but very rarely, I don't know why.

Comment: @VilleneuveMichaël your title says: *Make a right click with Super ( or another key )+left click* ? a shortcut key would work wherever you put the mouse cursor. Please mention what exactly the goal: to simulate Alt+right click? That is doable, but no custom shortcut key works with the mouse, but as said, another shortcut will work on where the mouse is located currently.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Indeed your solution pops the menu where the mouse is located which is fine for me 90% of the time, and I will stick to it if there is no other. The only problem is that with a touchscreen I have to left click before being able to right click. For eg : I have to click a link and launch the page but I wanted to pop the menu directly on the link

Comment: Sorry for asking, since I don't use a touch scree... would press left+hold be an option? All can be done.

Comment: Yes I would like that but I have seen and try this option and it doesn't work well with the touchscreen, I don't know why. It works great with the mouse however.